# No module named 'xlwt' even though I have it through Anaconda

Tags: python, xlwt

I've been trying to run import xlwt from a Python program and the prompter has told me that no such module exists. However I know that I have it through Anaconda. I also ran conda update xlwt in the prompt to know if it was the latest version, which it was (I have updated Anaconda as well). I'm using Python 3.4.

What I've tried is to include
    import sys
    sys.path.append('C:\Users\Guda\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages')

which got me the error

```
sys.path.append('C:\Users\Guda\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages')
               ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3:   truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I've also tried to copy the xlwt folder from C:....\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages to C:\Users...\Python34\Lib\site-packages and simply using import xlwt (removing the import sys and the sys.path.append command).

It gave me the error

```
 File "dataomv.py", line 5, in <module>
 import xlwt
 File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\xlwt\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
 from Workbook import Workbook
 ImportError: No module named 'Workbook'
```

From what I've googled I've seen that I must check whether **init**.py exists, which is does in the site-packages in both the Anaconda\Lib... and in Python34... folders.

Can anybody shed some light into this matter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your Unicode error has to do with the fact that backslash has a special meaning. You need to read up on strings (and either escaping backslashes or raw strings). Among other potential issues, `xlwt` doesn't support Python 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

Try module [xlwt-future](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt-future), it is written for python 3.x through  [future compatibility (of python 2 and 3) module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/future/0.13.0).